# Error when process run an instance of xterm with fork

Tags: c, linux, fork, xterm

I am given the task of forking n processes.

For each process, it must start an instance of /bin/xterm

I am done with the part of generating n processes and opening the xterm instance.

I got this output when I tried running the program. (Error in bold)

> Number of process to open is 1.
>
> Child (1): 3457
>
> **/bin/xterm: Xt error: Can't open display:**
>
> **/bin/xterm: DISPLAY is not set**

My code is below.

I tried googleing for the error but I have no luck so far.

Any solutions?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Number of process to open is %d.\n", num);
    int pid;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0) {
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            printf("Child (%d): %d\n", i + 1, getpid());
            char * const argv[] = {"/bin/xterm", NULL};
            char * const envp[] = {NULL};
            int rc = execve ("/bin/xterm", argv, envp);
            exit(0); 
        } else  {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are unecessrily waiting for each child to terminate!

Comment: Why do you want to assign value to argv[] while it is constant?

Comment: @Nullpointer thanks for the tip. I will remove the wait(NULL).. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little changed code works perfectly fine on my system:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Number of process to open is %d.\n", num);
    int pid;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0) {
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
      //printf("Child (%d): %d\n", i + 1, getpid());
            //char * const argv[] = {"/bin/xterm", NULL};
            //char * const envp[] = {NULL};
            execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "/usr/bin/xterm", NULL);
            //exit(0); 
        }else  {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, it's is possible to do it with execve?

Comment: May I ask how do you do it with execve based on my code above?

Answer (score 0):

The error was explained in the output you pasted:

```
 /bin/xterm: DISPLAY is not set
```

You need to set `DISPLAY` appropriately. Otherwise, it will have no way to know where to put its display.

Also, did you really want to `wait` for each child after creating it?

Comment: Just curious, how do i set the DISPLAY properly?

Comment: It depends where you want to display to go. You need to set it to the name/location of the display you want `xterm` to output to. Use `setenv`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
char *envp[] = {"TERM=vt100", "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin", "DISPLAY=:0.0",(char *) 0 };
```

Doing so you set the display on your machine.

Sorry I'm late.